# Python - How to convert elements in Panda from list to string

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

My df needs to have raw text, but the result i am getting comes inside brackets.

**Here is my code:**

```html
    chatroom = driver.find_element_by_class_name('_1_q7u')
    pos= 0
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Msgs','Time'], index=None)
    chat = driver.find_element_by_class_name('_19vo_').text
    for ol in chatroom.find_elements_by_class_name('message-in'):
        msgs = [k.text for k in ol.find_elements_by_class_name('_12pGw')]
        times = [k.text for k in ol.find_elements_by_class_name('_1RNhZ')]
        # df = [msgs,times]
        df.loc[pos] = [msgs, times]
        pos+=1
        print(df)
```

**Here is the output i have:**

```html
       Msgs     Time
0       [T]  [14:30]
1       [Z]  [14:36]
2       [Q]  [14:37]
3       [R]  [14:39]
```

**Here is the output i want:**

```html
       Msgs     Time
0       T     14:30
1       Z     14:36
2       Q     14:37
3       R     14:39
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
chatroom = driver.find_element_by_class_name('_1_q7u')
pos= 0
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Msgs','Time'], index=None)
chat = driver.find_element_by_class_name('_19vo_').text
for ol in chatroom.find_elements_by_class_name('message-in'):
    msgs = [k.text for k in ol.find_elements_by_class_name('_12pGw')][0]
    times = [k.text for k in ol.find_elements_by_class_name('_1RNhZ')][0]
    # df = [msgs,times]
    df.loc[pos] = [msgs, times]
    pos+=1
    print(df)
```